# casperjs + modal popup

Tags: popup, casperjs

i'm wondering why cannot get casperjs to recognize the modal popup:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://www.zulutrade.com/trader/140682?Lang=en');
casper.waitForSelector("form[name=aspnetForm] button#main_BtnFollow",
function success() {
    this.test.assertExists("form[name=aspnetForm] button#main_BtnFollow");
    this.click("form[name=aspnetForm] button#main_BtnFollow");
},
function fail() {
    this.test.assertExists("form[name=aspnetForm] button#main_BtnFollow");
});

casper.waitForPopup(/popup\.html$/, function() {
    this.test.assertEquals(this.popups.length, 1);
});
casper.run(function() {this.test.renderResults(true);});
```

running the above gives me timeout in the waitForPopup part..

How to make this work and how to use casper.withPopup properly with the popup?

Answer (score 3):

ah, are you using Resurrectio? in my experience, you need to tweak whatever script they generate. i mostly only use it for element names.

i'm only seeing asserts in your script. i think you need to tell casper to click on something before you see your modal. something like this maybe?

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.clickLabel('.Follow', 'a');
});

casper.waitForSelector("#modal_popup", function() {
    this.echo('see the modal!');
    this.capture('screenshotofmodal.png', { top: 0, left:0, width:1000, height:  4000}); 
 });
```

PS
using capture() is super helpful in troubleshooting your scripts. i have them as sort of like, breakpoints where i can easily see what's going on if a test that i know should be passing is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I've found myself implementing crude timeouts to get casper to play nicely with modal interactions:

```
casper.start(uri).then(function() {
  var slideshow = 'a.photo_gallery_icon_modal_launch';
  casper.wait(2000, function(){
    casper.thenEvaluate(function(sel) {
      $elem = jQuery(sel).first();
      $elem.click();
    }, slideshow)
  }).wait(1000, function(){
    // wait a sec for modal to show up before taking pic
    casper.capture('foo.png', {
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: 1280,
      height: 1024
    })
  })
});
```

There is also `waitForSelector` but I have not had as much success with it, because the contents of my modal are also asynchronous making the usage of `wait` or even `waitForUrl` more appropriate.

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector